# Which types of SSD are compatible with mac book pro mid-2012 (not retina)?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I am looking to replace the hard drive of my macbook pro mid 2012 with an SSD from an [ASUS taichi laptop](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS_TAICHI_21/specifications/) will the SSD from the taichi be compatible with my mac book?

Answer (score 1):

If your MacBook Pro is non-Retina : open both, take a look, if the storage connecter identical then you can switch between them.

If your MacBook Pro is Retina : simply NO :)